# How to make effect of text box value changes to a jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have  a text box which is holding some values and it has  a submit button  and it also have a slider so when i am clicking the button the slider changes but i want that i will not click on that submit button,instead changing the value in the textbox wil affect the slider moving.Here is  a fiddle  upto what i have done

http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/VbM9g/1/

This is the jQuery code

```
var slider = $(".slider").slider({
value: 50,
animate: true
});

$('#animate').click(function(){
slider.slider('value', $('#val').val());
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Keyup method.

```
$('#val').keyup(function(){
    slider.slider('value', $('#val').val());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3lackRos3/VbM9g/134/)

The change event is sent to an element when its value changes and keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can use the select element's change event:

```
$('#selectthing').change(function(){
    slider.slider('value', $('#val').val());
});
```

**Edit:**
Did you change the wording of your question?
If not, I may have misunderstood you.

If you want to target the text input, then, as the others suggest, attach an event listener to that:

```
$('#val').keyup(function(){
  slider.slider('value', $('#val').val());
});
```

Comment: can you edit in the fiddle please..its not working

Comment: Sure: [new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/8kybvvzx/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help **[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/VbM9g/137/):**

```
 $('#val').keyup(function(){
    slider.slider('value', $(this).val());
 });
```